Java multithreading with Spring JPA
I have to improve a process that is currently sequential, and i wanna make it multi-thread.
This process uses Spring JPA, with spring boot 2 and java 17.
I would like to have a feedback on the following mock-up and see if I can improve something, or there are errors.
The exportOrder() method is the one that contains the business logic. What happens is:

Validates the object
Maps OrdrDesc to ObjectA
Stores ObjectA (Different database then OrdrDesc)
Updates OrdrDesc
If ObjectA was stored, maps OrdrDesc to ObjectB
Stores ObjectB (Different database then OrdrDesc, but same as ObjectA)

Here is the code of the thread handling.
void test2() {
    final LinkedBlockingQueue<OrdrDesc> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    List<OrdrDesc> orders = getOrders(); // calls db - returns around 50k records
    for (OrdrDesc ordrDesc : orders) {
        try {
            queue.put(ordrDesc);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  // set interrupt flag
            System.out.println("Failed to consume order: " + ordrDesc);
        }
    }

    Runnable consumer = () -> {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() || !queue.isEmpty()) {
            OrdrDesc ordrDesc = queue.poll();
            if (ordrDesc != null) {
                exportOrder(ordrDesc);
            }
        }
    };

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        executorService.execute(consumer);
    }
}

